# NPM know if script running as a pre/post script

Tags: javascript, node.js

Let's say I have something like:

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "clean": "some-clean-script",
    "prebuild": "npm run clean",
    "build": "some-build-script"
  }
}
```

Inside my `some-clean-script` (which is written in NodeJS), I want to know if the script is running as part of the `prebuild` or was called directly.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a variable under `env.process` called `npm_lifecycle_event` that stores the key indicating the name of the script in `package.json`. So in your case, you can just check if `process.env.npm_lifecycle_event === 'clean'`.

For example, I run the following configuration:

```
{
  "name": "npm-test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "pretest": "node test.js",
    "test": "node index.js", 
    "posttest": "node test.js"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

test.js content:

`console.log(process.env.npm_lifecycle_event)`

and the output of the command `npm test`:

```
> npm-test@1.0.0 pretest /Users/bartlomiejgladys/Desktop/programming/npm-test
> node test.js

pretest

> npm-test@1.0.0 test /Users/bartlomiejgladys/Desktop/programming/npm-test
> node index.js

hi

> npm-test@1.0.0 posttest /Users/bartlomiejgladys/Desktop/programming/npm-test
> node test.js

posttest
```

Comment: That did not work; I tried `npm run clean` and `npm run build` and in both cases, the `process.env. npm_lifecycle_event` which is inside `some-clean-script`, it printed `clean`.

Comment: ohh, now i see - It's gonna work only if you define your prebuild as  "prebuild":"some-clean-script" instead of "prebuild":"npm run clean".

Comment: Thanks, ya that does answer the question. I've marked this as a solution. Thanks for your help :)